# Warning: mysqli_query(): Couldn't fetch mysqli in C:\ ... on line 13

Tags: php, mysqli

although this question has been asked (and answered) many times, I didn't find a solution to the problem.
Here is my code:

```
<?php
@session_start();

include("./include/config.php");
include("./include/db_connect.php");
include("functions.php");

if (!isset($_GET['artikelID'])){$_GET['artikelID'] = "";}
if (!isset($_SESSION['UserID'])){$_SESSION['UserID'] = "";}

$sql = "SELECT kundenID FROM kunden WHERE username = '".$_POST['myusername']."' AND password = '".md5($_POST['mypassword'])."' ";

$result = mysqli_query($connect, $sql) OR die("<pre>\n".$sql."</pre>\n".mysqli_connect_error()); // this is line 13

$row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result);

if (mysqli_num_rows($result)==1){
     doLogin($row['kundenID'], isset($_POST['Autologin']));
     header("location:cart.php?action=add&artikelID=".$_GET['artikelID']."&id=". $_SESSION['UserID'] ." ");
}

else {
     header("location:k_login.php?error=TRUE ");
}

include("./include/db_close.php");
?>
```

mysqli_connect_error() shows me the absolute correct sql-query; the sql-query is tested with a tool named mysql-front and brings exactly one (and the correct one) result, which is 'kundenID'.
I have tested many things (like  $_SESSION['connect'] or $_GLOBALS['connect'] instead of $connect in db_connect.db), but with no result.
Can anyone please help me?

-- Update --

Why does nobody answer?
Is the description of the problem unclear?
The db-connection is established like this:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
$connect = mysqli_connect($dbserver,$dbuser,$dbpass,$dbname);
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()){
  echo "Zeile ".__LINE__.": Datenbankverbindung ist fehlgeschlagen ! " . mysqli_connect_error();
  exit();
}
?>
```

All the db-variables are known in the checklogin-script (tested). All the $_POST-variables are also known in the checklogin-script (tested). I even tried a hard-coded sql-query (with the real data of the test-record in the db).
The result is still the same: mysqli_connect_error() reports the correct query - but then nothing more happens.
I have spent more than 10 hours in the meantime. I really would appreciate, if someone could help me.

Comment: What are the errors ?

Comment: Remove the `@` in front of `session_start`, and enable proper error_reporting if not already in place.

Comment: I removed the @. No error-reports. Nothing changes. Still the mysqli-warning.

Comment: I suspect you didn't get much response to this question because it was only tagged `mysqli`, and not `php`.  Not many people regularly monitor the mysqli tag, but lots monitor `php`. I have rectified that.

Comment: Following `mysqli_query()`, do not call `mysqli_connect_error()`. Instead call `mysqli_error($connect)`. The former will only report initial connection errors, not problems with the query execution.  When you test the SQL in another MySQL client, are you using the same connection username and password as your PHP code uses? You receive no connection error initially from `echo "Zeile " . __LINE__ .....` in db_connect.php?

Comment: It took some time, but I solved the problem (I'm hobby-programmer).
1. my error-reporting was unsufficient, otherwise I had seen that var_dump($connect) returned empty results.
2. var_dump results were empty, because the scirpt referred to a function doLogin() that is defined in another script. Because I built all my scripts with db-connect and db-close, the db-connection was closed in the meantime. I removed db-close in the scripts, so the connection is still open - and now it works.

Answer (score 0):

`Couldn't fetch mysqli` means that PHP is unable to identify the contents of your `$connect` variable as a valid mysqli connection. Try adding some error handling into `"./include/db_connect.php"` to get an idea of what happened to the mysqli connection that is preventing you from using it.